# Modeling an Association Class In Rails - Student Registration Example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uml, class-diagram, object-diagram

I'm trying to model the classic example of a association model and link objects.  The image below sets forth a class diagram showing association classes and Object diagram showing link objects.

[image: Association class and link objects]

The image shows a part an object diagram representing a student, Mary Jones, and the courses she has registered for in the Fall 2010 term: MKT350 and MIS385. Corresponding to an association class in a class diagram, link objects are present in an object diagram. In this example, there are two link objects (shown as :Registration) for the Registration association class, capturing the two course registrations.

Registration is the Association Class 
:Registration is the link objects

My question is how would I model something like this in Rails /ActiveRecord

Comment: So, what's your problem? Did you tried to write the code and has some problem? Did you read the ActiveRecord association guide? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Yes, I have read the association section of the rails guide and I don't see where it addresses an association class.   Most of the time in the guide is devoted to associations between two models. I believe, this is something slightly different.

Comment: Please read section 2.4 and 2.6. They are for many-to-many association.

Comment: OK, so you're saying that the "Association Class" is simply the join table between student and course and that the checkElibility() is simply a method in the join table.  Is it really that straightforward.

Comment: Yes. Posted my answer. I can write some sample code, but I think it will be a good exercise for you.

Comment: One last comment: is it strange to have 1-1 association between account and registration? If a student has 5 courses, he can have 5 different account and password. In general, account should be associated to user (student).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [A Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for the association basics, especially `has_many :through` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` sections.

`has_and_belongs_to_many` is only suitable for you don't need other information except the many-to-many association. You don't need to create a model class for the join table. If you are not sure, use `has_many :through` instead.

In your case, you can use `has_many :through` association. In Registration class, you can use [ActiveRecord validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) to check eligibility.